# Connecting Postgres and Node App with fly.io using knex.js

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js, fly

Has anyone tried deploying postgres and node app with fly.io using knex?

I am trying to figure out what the connection string would be:
`knex({ client: "pg", connection: { host: process.env.DATABASE_URL, }, });`

What would be the connection string be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `knex` with a Postgres database, the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is typically a connection string that includes the username, password, host, port, and database name.

```
postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase
```

In the `knex` configuration, you can simply provide this `DATABASE_URL` as the connection. Knex can parse connection strings directly:

```
knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
});
```

In the context of `fly.io`, you'd generally obtain your `DATABASE_URL` as an environment variable set within your Fly.io application configuration.